# Memoir Class 2 Column Footnotes

Tags: footnotes, memoir

Why does the footnote mark appear on the inside instead of the outside margin when using `\twocolumnfootnotes` in the Memoir class? I cannot use `\dblfnote` since my document will not compile with it.

I think it has something to do with the document being RTL. Is there a way to change the position of the footnote mark?

I have attahced a MWE to show the problem:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily{\syriacfont}{Serto Antioch Bible}
\setmainlanguage{syriac}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={DejaVu Serif Bold}]{Serto Antioch Bible}

\twocolumnfootnotes

\begin{document}

ܒ݁ܪܺܫܺܝܬ݂ ܐܺܝܬ݂ܰܘܗ̱ܝ ܗ̱ܘܳܐ ܡܶܠܬ݂ܳܐ.\footnote{\LR{Footnote 1}}
ܘܗܽܘ ܡܶܠܬ݂ܳܐ.\footnote{\LR{Footnote 2}}
ܐܺܝܬ݂ܰܘܗ̱ܝ ܗ̱ܘܳܐ ܠܘܳܬ݂ ܐܰܠܳܗܳܐ.\footnote{\LR{Footnote 3}}

\end{document}
```